# Angular directive with scope : @ not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my directive code which works fine:

```
.directive('myGrid',function(){
return {
  restrict:'E',
  scope:{
    info:'=info'
  },
  templateUrl : '/directiveGrid.html'
}
```

})

Here is a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/jay3dec/pen/GZjQao)

But if I change the scope like :

```
    .directive('myGrid',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{
        info:'@info'
      },
      templateUrl : '/directiveGrid.html'
    }
  })
```

It doesn't work. Here is the second [demo](http://codepen.io/jay3dec/pen/oxzERr)

Comment: '=' provide two way binding, and '@' only pass a string value. they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you have use `@` for isolate scope binding, it passes the value from attribute to directive. Basically while passing value using `@` it `stringify` that value and before passing it to directive. So value went to directive is not in a `JSON` format, it get stringified before reach to directive(data type changed to `string`).

If you do `{{info}}` you will see the result(which is nothing but `string`). It has been converted to string thats why you can't see ng-repear working

Preferred approach would be use =, that will do two things

1. Two way binding
2. It preserves data-type of value when value passes to directive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some explanation:

**@** binds a local/directive scope property to the evaluated value of the DOM attribute. Since attribute values are always strings, you will always end up with a string value for this property in the directive's scope when using @.

@ allows a value defined on the directive attribute to be passed to the directive's isolate scope.

**=** binds a local/directive scope property to a parent scope property. So with =, you use the parent model/scope property name as the value of the DOM attribute. You can't use {{}}s with =.

= sets up a two-way binding expression between the directive's isolate scope and the parent scope. Changes in the child scope and propagated to the parent and vice-versa. Think of = as a combination of @ and &. Screencast on = is here: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-two-way-binding

Yes, bidirectional binding (**=**) allows the local/directive scope and the parent scope to share data. "Expression binding" allows the directive to call an expression (or function) defined by a DOM attribute -- and you can also pass data as arguments to the expression or function. So, if you don't need to share data with the parent -- you just want to call a function defined in the parent scope -- you can use the & syntax.